# How do I test a module when the behaviour depends on Application.get_env/3?

Tags: testing, elixir, elixir-mix

I'm making a library with a module that when `use`'d injects some functions dependant on the contents of a directory, and I want to test the behaviour with different directories. Currently I get the path to the directory through application config with `Application.get_env/3`.

If I'm changing the directory `Application.put_env/4` it means my tests have to run sequentially as this is effective a global value, correct?

Can I stub out the call to `Application.get_env/3`? Or should I be passing in the value in another way? (such as via the `use` macro)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to pass in the value as an argument. Your module could depend on `Application.get_env` only absent a passed in value. Something like:

```
Application.put_env(MyApplication, :some_key, "hello")

defmodule Test do
  def test(string \\ Application.get_env(MyApplication, :some_key)) do
    IO.inspect(string)
  end
end

# Default behaviour    
Test.test           # => "hello"

# In your tests
Test.test("world")  # => "world"
```

Comment: I think this has a **huge** disadvantage: compile-time optimization. I often find myself in need to read the configuration at compile-time and use it to do some compile-time work.

Comment: If the argument is passed into a macro then we can still get compile time optimisation.
I was leaning towards this sort of method, though I would like to know if there's a better way to handle this.